# Recovering signal statistics from non-uniform sampled signal

Tags: estimation, nonuniform

I'm interested in estimating the mean and standard deviation of a signal that was sampled non-uniformly. Assuming I have an estimate of the signal bandwidth, what algorithms would provide estimates of these quantities?

I imagine simply weighting the values by their relative frequencies could work. But is this actually a good approach? Does it have some theoretical guarantee like how the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean?

I'd appreciate any insight or references I could turn to. Thank you.

Comment: I would use the sample mean for the mean. the sample variance needs to be divided by the degrees of freedom which is the tricky part.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, won't the vanilla sample mean bias the estimate toward those parts of the signal where the sampling frequency is higher?

Comment: it depends on what you are developing statistics on.  perhaps you can elaborate on what your goal is. a mean , a spectral mean? a histogram of amplitudes?

Comment: I'm looking for the mean of the signal. I suppose I'm implicitly modeling the signal as a continuous time signal that was sampled. In that case, I'm looking for an estimate of the mean of the continuous time signal.

Comment: Hi! Why don't you first convert those samples to uniform ones ?

Comment: @Fat32: Hi! By resampling, do you mean coming up with an interpolation (e.g. splines), then sampling the interpolation at regular intervals? I think that could work, it just seemed like overkill since I only want the mean and std. (And actually, if I had a spline representation or similar, I think I could find the mean and std without the resampling.) I was hoping there was some literature on point estimates for signals or something that I could turn to. But if not, then maybe reconstructing the signal _then_ computing whatever statistics I need is the way to go.

Comment: yes, any convenient interpolation would work and yes there's some extra processing but afaik there's no shurtcut here...

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks! That was my suspicion, but I was indeed hoping for a shortcut. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Fat32: You might also want to provide an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: It's not an answer but just a suggestion. May be someone else can come with a different idea.